# How to add 2 select fields (combobox) to woocommerce checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am developing an online store that offers local delivery days according to zip code. I have limited the zip codes with a selection using this snippet

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_postcode_field');
function custom_override_default_postcode_field ($address_fields) {
    // Zip codes
    $postcode_array = array (
        '28001' => '28001',
        '28002' => '28002',
        '28923' => '28923'
    );
    $address_fields['postcode']['type']    = 'select';
    $address_fields['postcode']['options'] = $postcode_array;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

I am using the plugin [woocommerce checkout field](https://woocommerce.com/es-es/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/) editor and I've added field "delivery days", which is a select field with the values ​​Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ...

Now, I want to make the second field dependent on the first, according to my client's specifications, for example:

Zip code 28001 / Delivery Days Monday and Wednesday

Zip code 28002 / Delivery days Tuesday and Thursday

Zip code 28923 / Delivery Days Friday and Sunday

That is, when the buyer chooses a postal code, it only shows him to choose the corresponding days.

If there is a way to do that without the plugin I think it will be better

Thanks a lot for your help,
Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This required a lots of customization. Try the below code. code goes to your active theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_postcode_field');
function custom_override_default_postcode_field ($address_fields) {
    // Zip codes
    $postcode_array = array (
        '28001' => '28001',
        '28002' => '28002',
        '28923' => '28923'
    );
    $address_fields['postcode']['type']    = 'select';
    $address_fields['postcode']['options'] = $postcode_array;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

You can add a new dropdown field `Delivery days` using the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_delivery_days_woocommerce_billing_fields' );
function custom_delivery_days_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    
     $fields['billing']['delivery_days'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Delivery days', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('dropdown', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'       => true,
        'priority'    => 95,
        'type'        => 'custom_select',
        'options'     => array(
            'monday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Monday', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28001',
            ),
            'tuesday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Tuesday', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28002',
            ),
            'wednesday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Wednesday', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28001',
            ),
            'thursday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Thursday', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28002',
            ),
            'friday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Friday', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28923',
            ),
            'sunday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Sunday', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28923',
            )
        )
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

Now as per your requirement I will use data attr for show hide select option based on another select option. but in woocommerce default select dropdown, there is now a way to add data attr to select. so for this, I created the `custom_select` type so we can add data attr. so as you can see in above `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter hook i set `'type'        => 'custom_select',`.

You can add new your custom field type using the `woocommerce_form_field` filter hook.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'add_custom_select', 10 , 4 );
function add_custom_select( $field, $key, $args, $value  ){

    if( $args['type'] == 'custom_select' ){

        if ( $args['required'] ) {
            $args['class'][] = 'validate-required';
            $required        = '&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="' . esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' ) . '">*</abbr>';
        } else {
            $required = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        }

        $field   = '';
        $options = '';

        if ( ! empty( $args['options'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $args['options'] as $option_key => $option_text ) {
                if ( '' === $option_key ) {
                    // If we have a blank option, select2 needs a placeholder.
                    if ( empty( $args['placeholder'] ) ) {
                        $args['placeholder'] = $option_text['label'] ? $option_text['label'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );
                    }
                    $custom_attributes[] = 'data-allow_clear="true"';
                }
                $options .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" ' . selected( $value, $option_key, false ) . ' data-'.$option_text['data_attr_name'].'="'.$option_text['data_attr_value'].'" >'  . esc_html( $option_text['label'] ) . '</option>';
            }

            $field .= '<select name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '" class="select ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' data-placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '">
                    ' . $options . '
                </select>';
        }

        $field_container = '<p class="form-row %1$s" id="%2$s" data-priority="' . esc_attr( $sort ) . '">%3$s</p>';
        
        if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {
            $field_html = '';

            if ( $args['label'] && 'checkbox' !== $args['type'] ) {
                $field_html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $label_id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $args['label'] ) . $required . '</label>';
            }

            $field_html .= '<span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">' . $field;

            if ( $args['description'] ) {
                $field_html .= '<span class="description" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '-description" aria-hidden="true">' . wp_kses_post( $args['description'] ) . '</span>';
            }

            $field_html .= '</span>';

            $container_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) );
            $container_id    = esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '_field';
            $field           = sprintf( $field_container, $container_class, $container_id, $field_html );
        }

        return $field;

    }

    return $field;

}
```

Now on the `billing_postcode` change, you have to get the `billing_postcode` value that you need to compare with `delivery_days` dropdown option `data-post-code` and based on that you can show hide.

```
function add_custom_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $('#billing_postcode').on('change', function(){
            var postcode = $(this).val();
            var days  = $('#delivery_days');
            var i     = 1;
            $('option', days).filter(function(){
                if ( $(this).attr('data-post-code') === postcode ) {
                    $(this).show();
                    if( i == 1 ){
                      $("#delivery_days").val($(this).val());
                    }
                    i++;
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            });
            $('#billing_postcode').trigger('change');
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_js', 10, 1 );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

Comment: Ooh @bhautik you are a genius. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's working fine, except for one thing ¿What if Delivery Days overlaps for 2 or more postal codes?

Let's suppose Delivery days for postal code 28001 are Monday, Wednesday and friday, and for postal code 28002 are Friday and Saturday. As you can see, FRIDAY is common day for both postal codes.

¿How to assing more than one postal code to the same day?

Comment: It's Ready! when delivery days overlaps, I need to repeat option for 2 postal codes!

            'monday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Lunes', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28001',
            ),
            'monday' => array(
                'label' =>  __('Lunes', 'woocommerce' ),
                'data_attr_name'  => 'post-code',
                'data_attr_value' => '28923',
            ),